# What other worms do I need to catch?

Tags: cats, parasites

I am using [revolution](https://www.revolution.com.au/) on my cats.

It kills:

- Flea infestations (killing adult fleas)
- Flea eggs
- Flea larvae
- Prevents heartworm
- Hookworm
- Roundworm
- Ear mites

It's applied topically to the skin, so there's no need to administer oral medicine.

Are these all the worms I need to catch, or should I be using a more general purpose oral wormer?

Comment: Does your cat currently have worms?

Comment: @ChristyB. not sure, He's been losing weight, I need to take him to the vet :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tapeworms and lungworms too. The common misconception with tapeworms is that they can only be infected if they have fleas, but if a cat eats or catches a rodent or other animal, and it has the parasite it can still be caught.

Good news for you is revolution works for both tapeworms and lungworms as well! Revolution is a great medication. It also treats and prevents some other micro organism parasites that can grow in the digestive tract (ex. Toxoplasma).